# Self-signed сертификат на PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, x509, x509certificate

Подскажите как создать self-sigh сертификат используя Bouncy Castle PCL?
Нужно создавать такой сертификат на xamarin клиенте и закидывать его потом на сервер.